# Convert column of lists to columns of True/False if it belongs to the lists

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, pulp

I have the following DataFrame

```
    Codice  Sem CFU Rating  Gruppo
0   51132   1   10  0.0 [STAT]
1   51197   1   5   0.0 [ING]
2   52354   1   5   0.0 [ING]
3   52496   1   10  0.0 [MST]
4   52498   2   10  0.0 [MST]
... ... ... ... ... ...
57  97667   1   8   3.0 [MTM]
58  97673   2   8   0.0 [MTM]
59  97683   2   5   5.0 [STAT, ING]
60  97690   2   12  0.0 [MST]
61  97725   2   10  0.0 [CSCL, MTM]
```

As you see, the `Gruppo` column is made of lists of a finite number of unique elements. I'm trying to generate from this a DF to be used in `pulp` for something like "if `Codice` belongs to `Gruppo`", thus I need a DF (or matrix, but I wanted to indexise using `Codice` and not just an ordinary integer) made like this:

```
    Codice  STAT    ING ... MST
0   51132   True    False   ... False
1   51197   False   True    ... False
```

Basically True/False whether the corresponding list contains `ING,STAT,MST,...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General solution if `Codice` are or not unique use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and test if not `0`:

```
df1 = df.explode('Gruppo')
df2 = pd.crosstab(df1['Codice'], df1['Gruppo']).ne(0).reset_index()
```

Or use [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) with aggregate `max` and compare for equal `1`:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df2 = (pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['Gruppo']),
                    columns=mlb.classes_, 
                    index=df['Codice']).groupby(level=0).max().eq(1))
```

---

If values in `Codice` are unique is possible remove aggregation:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df2 = (pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['Gruppo']),
                    columns=mlb.classes_, 
                    index=df['Codice']).eq(1))
```